# PHP What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to use PHP to detect certain languages. However, no matter what, it only echos "FR" I don't know why.

```
<?php
    $lang = "en";
    if ($lang == "fr" OR "nl") {
        echo "FR";
    } else {
        echo "Nope";
    }
?>
```

EDIT:
How about this?

```
<?php
    $lang = "FR";
    $numarray = array(1, 2); //change the values accordingly.
    if ($lang === "fr" OR $lang === "nl") {
        echo "FR";
    } elseif(array_rand($numarray) == 1) {
        echo "Outcome1";
    } else {
        echo "Outcome2";
    }
?>
```

EDIT:
I found the problem. Strings are case sensitive.

Comment: Basically what you are doing is Oring "fr" and "nL" and THEN checking if that is the language. Your statement is equivalent to $lange == ("fr" OR "nl") which is not what you are assuming.

Comment: You may want to make it case insensitive: e.g. ` if (strtolower($lang)) == 'fr'`, depends on where you are getting $lang from.  But your FR and fr will not match.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lang = "en";
if ($lang === "fr" OR $lang === "nl") {
    echo "FR";
} else {
    echo "Nope";
}
```

You almost had it. OR needs two statements so just think of each side of the or needing brackets if (($land === "fr") OR ($land === "nl"))

Comment: You are beautiful.
What about this?
    <?php
        $lang = "FR";
        $numarray = array(1, 2); //change the values accordingly.
        if ($lang === "fr" OR $lang === "nl") {
            echo "FR";
        } elseif(array_rand($numarray) == 1) {
            echo "Outcome1";
        } else {
            echo "Outcome2";
        }
?>

Answer (score 0):

see u r using OR incorrectly
try this it works

```
<?php
    $lang = "en";
    if ($lang == "fr" or $lang== "nl") {
        echo "FR";
    } else {
        echo "Nope";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please check out the edit and see what's wrong there?

Comment: This will give result always either outcome1 or outcome 2, because '===' checks the identicalness and "FR" is equal to "fr" in terms of value but not identical

Answer (score 0):

`==` comparison operator will give unexpected results specially when using strings..

try using the following script

```
<?php
    $lang = "en";
    if ($lang === "fr" OR $lang === "nl") {
        echo "FR";
    } else {
        echo "Nope";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please check out the edit and see what's wrong there?

Comment: How would == vs. === make a difference with strings?  A string is a string and there is not TYPE issues.  Now if its TRUE FALSE vs. one zero then === is needed. Like when a false is returned on error when a zero would be a legitimate return value e.g. strpos().   There are no Type issues with strings.

Comment: True.. in this very as the $lang is defined well there would be no problem in using == .. But it's always safe to use === when comparing strings.. @XDShiftBlue : Hope you got the answer..